# Retrieve product custom media image label in magento

Tags: image, magento, product

I have a custom block loading products on my front page that loads the four newest products that have a custom product picture attribute set via:

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter("image_feature_front_right", array("notnull" => 1));
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter("image_feature_front_right", array("neq" => 'no_selection'));
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('updated_at', 'DESC');
$_productCollection->setPageSize(4);
```

What I am trying to do is grab the `image_feature_front_right` label as set in the back-end, but have been unable to do so. Here is my code for displaying the products on the front end:

```
<?php foreach($_productCollection as $_product) : ?>
    <div class="fll frontSale">
        <div class="productImageWrap">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image_feature_front_right')->directResize(230,315,4) ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="salesItemInfo">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl($_product->getUrlPath()) ?>"><p class="caps"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName());?></p></a>
            <p class="nocaps"><?php echo $this->getImageLabel($_product, 'image_feature_front_right') ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I read that `$this->getImageLabel($_product, 'image_feature_front_right')` was the way to do it, but produces nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Tre

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your custom block would need to inherit from Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract to give access to that method.

You could also use the code directly from the method in the template:

```
$label = $_product->getData('image_feature_front_right');
if (empty($label)) {
    $label = $_product->getName();
}
```

Comment: How would I make it inherit? I'm still attempting to wrap my head around Magento.

Comment: In your block class declaration use "class Your_Block_Class extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product Abstract" as the class declaration line.  There's some solid tutorials on the Magento.com website laying out how blocks relate to templates which should point you in a good direction.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you asked this same question in another thread, so to help others who might be searching for an answer, I'll anser it here as well:

I imagine this is some sort of magento bug. The issue seems to be that the Magento core is not setting the custom_image_label attribute. Whereas for the default built-in images [image, small_image, thumbnail_image] it does set these attributes - so you could do something like:

```
$_product->getData('small_image_label');
```

If you look at `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getImageLabel()` it just appends '_label' to the `$mediaAttributeCode` that you pass in as the 2nd param and calls `$_product->getData()`.

If you call `$_product->getData('media_gallery');`  you'll see the custom image label is available. It's just nested in an array. So use this function:

```
function getImageLabel($_product, $key) {
    $gallery = $_product->getData('media_gallery');
    $file = $_product->getData($key);
    if ($file && $gallery && array_key_exists('images', $gallery)) {    
        foreach ($gallery['images'] as $image) {
            if ($image['file'] == $file)
                return $image['label'];
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

It'd be prudent to extend the Magento core code (Ideally `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`, but I don't think Magento lets you override Abstract classes), but if you need a quick hack - just stick this function in your phtml file then call:

```
<?php echo getImageLabel($_product, 'image_feature_front_right')?>
```

Comment: Had the exact same problem on Magento 2.3. Exact code still works!